# How to only get One Signal's Additional Data 'value' pair?

Tags: swift, push-notification, onesignal

Hi guys I'm trying to figure out how the One Signal Additional Data works and catch if someone comes from a push notification.

I can get the information if the 'key' and the 'value' are equal in additional data as you see in my code:

```
if payload.additionalData != nil {
 if payload.additionalData["actionName"] as? String == "FirstAction" {
  UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "actionFound")
 }
}
```

How can I solve this? For some reason, I just need that 'value' pair (in this case "FirstAction") and print it to the console.

[image: one signal pic]

Thanks.

Comment: From your code, I know that ``additionalData`` is a Dictionary and you get value of the key ``actionName`` from the dictionary and compare it with ``FirstAction``. So I don't know what is ``value`` pair you talking about?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Actually, `FirstAction` is the `value` of the `actionName`.

Comment: Yes. So that's the reason I don't know the question and the problem you facing.

Comment: So I basically need to get that value pair whatever it is (in my example it is FirstAction). `key` -> `actionName` will always be the same. But the `value` will always be different.

Comment: Then you just need ``let value = payload.additionalData["actionName"]`` you will get ``Any?`` value - Of course can be nil too. Then you can cast or covert it to any type you want.